# Printing image on first click does not show the image

Tags: javascript

Below java script to print image onClick is not working properly. It doesnt load the image on first click. When user clicks on button it opens blank/broken image. After closing the first print window then on second click it shows the image.

```
<a href="#" onclick="VoucherPrint('output/image.jpg'); return false;">Print Voucher</a>

function VoucherSourcetoPrint(source) {
    return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
    "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
    "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
    "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
    "<img src='" + source + "' /></body></html>";
}
function VoucherPrint(source) {
    Pagelink = "about:blank";
    var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
    pwa.document.open();
    pwa.document.write(VoucherSourcetoPrint(source));
    pwa.document.close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the step1() and step2() functions?

Comment: @OzgurSar well if you can make within the VoucherPrint no issue please help

Comment: Your code worked fine for me with the first click. Try to extend the timeout. Potentially some latency with your image loading.

Comment: @farhodius can you please make an answer with timeout and i will try

Comment: I think solution proposed by @mplungjan looks better in terms of using `onload` event. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too complicated.

Try this instead

```js
document.getElementById("printVoucher").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const img = e.target.dataset.src;
  const html = `<body onload="window.print();setTimout(function() {window.close()},500)"><img src="${img}" /></body>`;
  const pwa = window.open("", e.target.target);
  if (pwa) {
    pwa.document.open();
    pwa.document.write(html);
    pwa.document.close();
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link
  }
  else e.target.href=img; // popup blocker. Open the image in a new tab
})
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="printVoucher" data-src="output/image.jpg">Print Voucher</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your kind help. one thing it is not closing the new opened window after print

Comment: I used setTimeout like you did. If the print dialog does not open it’s due to a popup blocker